# How to extract commas in between square brackets in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++, brackets

For example:

```
[TEXT1,TEXT2,TEXT3]
```

my expression: `[\[].*,.*[\]]`

Finds strings with commas (in between brackets,) but I only want to explicitly match the comma that exists in the square brackets.

I need to replace the commas with spaces - but only in the square brackets.

I've tried `[\[],[\]]` but that doesn't work -

`\[(.*?)\]` will find the text in between as well - but I do not want the entire string.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to just find commas in between the brackets?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. [Text1,Text2,Text3] can also exist in a line with other commas - but I only want the commas in the square brackets.

Answer (score 6):

Find what:

```
(?:\[|(?!^)\G)[^,\]]*\K,
```

Replace with:
<kbd>space</kbd>

---

Break-down:

- <kbd>`(?:\[|(?!^)\G)`</kbd> Matches the opening `[` or the [end of last match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) `(?!^)\G`.
- <kbd>`[^,\]]*`</kbd> Consumes all chars until the next comma.
- <kbd>`\K`</kbd> Tells the regex engine to [discard what it has matched so far](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html).
- <kbd>`,`</kbd> Finally matches the comma.

Comment: Bravo. I still find `\G` and `\K` confusing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I was looking to solve this same issue and found a solution with this: `,(?=[^\[]*\])`

I hope it helps someone who stumbles on this post!

Note: Using Text Wrangler instead of Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets generally need to be escaped in regex, so something like

```
\[.*(,).*\]
```

could work - where the regex group #1 (which is the captured/replaceable part in other tools, I don't have notepad++) would be the single comma in brackets that you want.

Comment: He escaped them, but didn't use markdown properly and it stripped the backslashes. I fixed the question.

Comment: The above gives me the same result that I got earlier in notepad++ I can only get the text in between the brackets but not the commas alone.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
(?<=[\[,])[^\],]*(,)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eX7oH2/1)

Comment: this helps but I still have an issue. Sorry I should have been more clear. [Text1,Text2,Text3] can also exist in a line with other commas - but I only want the commas in the square brackets.  So if I have a line eg:  Hello,world,[Text1,Text2,Text3],hello  I only want the commas returned in the square brackets.