# Match all commas inside brackets use regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to find all commas only inside brackets, and I find this regex expression `"(?:\[|(?!^)\G)[^,\]]*\K,"` is perfect, but not support in Java.

So can anyone help me to rewrite this expression? I tried but failed.

For example: **"NVL(ab, bc, cd),"** in this case I just want to match the commas after **ab** and **bc** and replace them.

Comment: Try this: `,(?=[^\(]*\))` From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58408556/14524999

Comment: It works, but in this case "NVLab, bc, cd)," has a minor defect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java supports a finite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion, so you can match a comma assering a `[` to the left and `]` to the right.

Assuming there are no nested square brackets:

```
(?<=\[[^\]\[]{0,100}),(?=[^\]\[]*])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\[[^\]\[]{0,100})` Positive lookbehind, assert `[` to the left followed for example a finite range of 0 - 100 occurrences of any char except `[` and `]`
- `,` Match the comma that you want to replace
- `(?=[^\]\[]*])` Positive lookahead, assert `]` to the right

For example:

```
String regex = "(?<=\\[[^\\]\\[]{0,100}),(?=[^\\]\\[]*])";
String string = "test , test ,, [,,test,]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("X"));
```

Output

```
test , test ,, [XXtestX]
```

See s [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gnVeTH/1) and a  [Java demo](https://ideone.com/avjyyX).